# I can't get file redirection to work with Visual Studio 2022 and C++

Tags: c++

I am completely new to programming, and I am currently working through C++ primer 5th edition using Visual Studio 2022 and am at the end of chapter 1 (the bookstore problem). The book mentions file redirection letting you use a file as an input and then writing to an output file. It's example is this: $ addItems outfile     but when I try to enter that type of command into the window that pops up when I run my program, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
    Sales_item currTrans, trans;
    std::cout << "Enter some ISBNs";
    if (std::cin >> currTrans) {
        int cnt = 1;
        while (std::cin >> trans) {
            if (currTrans.isbn() == trans.isbn()) 
                ++cnt;
            else {
                std::cout << currTrans << " occurs "
                    << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
                currTrans = trans;
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << currTrans << " occurs "
            << cnt << " times." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have put .txt files named input.txt and output.txt into the folder with my source code, and the folder with my exe, but I can't seem to get the program to read from the input file or write to the output file.
For example:

```
$ primer-chapter1-exercises.exe < input.txt >> output.txt
```

or

```
< $(E:\coding-stuff\cpp-primer\primer-chapter1-exercises\x64\Debug\primer-chapter1-exercises.exe)input.txt>>output.txt
```

Neither command outputs anything into the terminal or the output.txt file.

Solution:
I was attempting to use file redirection in my program's terminal (through vs 2022) like it was a cmd. I did some more research, found out about the fstream and using that I was able to get my program to read and write files.

Comment: The directory containing your source code, the directory containing your executable, and current working directory (when your program is running) are possibly all different.    Since you haven't specified full paths (directory and filename) the input file must exist in the current working directory, and output file will be created (or found if appending to it) also in the current working directory.   If running from a command line (e.g. cmd) the current working directory is shown by the `cd` command (no arguments).  If running the program in an IDE, it is set by the IDE.

Comment: what "window that pops up"?
If you are running under VS2022 and it pops up a window, it is too late. Your program has already loaded by that point. You would need to run with something like `cmd.exe /c ${executable} < input.txt >> output.txt`

Comment: Does running the program from the same terminal work without the redirections?

Comment: @AlanBirtles (well -- without the 2nd redirection `:)`

Comment: The book assumes that you're running your programs from the command line, not launching them from an IDE.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm pretty sure redirections work when launching programs from the vs debugger